# prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a+2b^2}\ge 1$

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a+2b^2}\ge 1$$ holds for all positives $a,b,c$ when $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=3$ or $ab+bc+ca=3$

---

**Background** Taking $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=3$ This was left as an exercise to the reader in the book 'Secrets in inequalities'.This comes under the section Cauchy Reverse technique'.i.e the sum is rewritten  as :$$\sum_{cyc} a- \frac{ab^2}{a+2b^2}\ge a-\frac{2}{3}\sum_{cyc}{(ab)}^{2/3}$$ which is true by AM-GM.($a+b^2+b^2\ge 3{(a. b^4)}^{1/3}$)

By QM-AM inequality $$\sum_{cyc}a\ge \frac{{ \left(\sum \sqrt{a} \right)}^2}{3}=3$$.

we are left to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}{(ab)}^{2/3}\le 3$$ .But i am not able to prove this .Even the case when $ab+bc+ca=3$ seems difficult to me.

Please note I am looking for a solution using this cuchy reverse technique and AM-GM only.

Comment: I think you can prove by AM GM that $$\dfrac{1}{3}\sum x^{2/3} \le\left(\dfrac{1}{3} \sum x\right)^{2/3}$$ by expanding with the third power and replace $x=ab$

Comment: @BookOfFlames  Botha are differnt problems

Comment: Yes, I did not see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, for $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=3$ we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2}\leq3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4}\leq3,$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives such that $a+b+c=3,$ which is true by AM-GM and Schur:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4}=\sum_{cyc}ab\sqrt[3]{ab}\leq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}ab(1+a+b)\leq3.$$

Comment: thank you  for answer,but is there a way to eliminate schur?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore  Instead of Schur  we can use SOS, uvw, BW and more...But I don't see a solution for the last step by AM-GM.

Answer (score 3):

For $ab+bc+ca=3.$ We need to prove
$$ a+b+c \geqslant 1 + \frac{2}{3}\sum (ab)^{2/3}.$$
From condition we get
$$a+b+c \geqslant \sqrt{3(ab+bc+ca)}=3.$$
Now, using the AM-GM inequality we have
$$\sum (ab)^{2/3} = \sum \sqrt[3]{1 \cdot ab \cdot ab} \leqslant \sum \frac{1+2ab}{3} = 1+\frac{2}{3}(ab+bc+ca)=3.$$
So
$$1 + \frac{2}{3}\sum (ab)^{2/3} \leqslant 1 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot 3=3 \leqslant a+b+c.$$
Done.